# Ideas for a new way of storing very large numbers (for 3D coordinates)

Tags: numbers, point, floating

When creating a large game world, the standard seems to be to go with a floating point number, specifically a double precision float, for world coordinates.  You could use a 64 bit integer, which gives you plus or minus 9 quintillion range, (9 x 10^18), but then you'd be dealing in units of a millimetre, which isn't as comfortable as using say metres.

We all know that the bigger a floating point number gets, the less precision it has and the more likely the number will be off by a large margin.  In most open world games, you don't really see maps larger than about 6km squared.  GTA V (6 by 12), Witcher 3( two separate maps of about 4 by 4), Fallout games, roughly comparable, Just Cause games, slightly larger (around the 20km squared mark), Need for Speed games, same, 4ish squared, maybe 5, Elder Scrolls games, roughly the same, you get the idea.  Most of these games aren't a problem for double precision floating point numbers.

But then you have games and cases where the world is particularly enormous, and I guess these games are mostly space themed games, where the action takes place in solar systems, galaxies, etc.  I just read thread on reddit about how the developers said that the move to a 64 bit version of the game Space Engineers allowed them to enormously enlarge the scope of the game world, saying they can now fill about 13 astronomical units, or about 2 billion kilometres.  Still, Pluto is about 50 AU away at aphelion or 7.5 billion kilometres away.  This makes me wonder how games like Star Citizen or Elite Dangerous do it, I'm guessing stitching together different maps seamlessly.

I've heard of the long double and the quad, but the long double doesn't seem to work on most architectures and compilers, and there's little information on the quad.

But that leads me to topic of ideas I'm sure everyone's had at some point, and that is to use more than one data type and using them together.  For example, I've already said that with a 64 bit signed integer you can get one integer precision up to 9 quintillion.  Say for example you let that 64 bit int be your metres unit.  This would give you a world space of 9 quadrillion kilometres.  Then all you would need is an extra two bytes, a 16 bit integer, can hold around 65,000 values, and use these two bytes as your millimetres.  A value of 2 would be 2 millimetres, a value of 25 would be 2.5 centimetres, a value of 500 would be half a metre.  This way you would have millimetre resolution in your world coordinates.

I'm fairly confident that it won't be a problem adding and subtracting such composite numbers (let's call em), but multiplying and dividing seems a bit trickier.  But, after all's said and done, is it even true that by carrying out multiple operations on two integer types (actually four integer types when you put two numbers together) would be more speedy or efficient than using floating point number arithmetic?

Comment: Some languages have BigDecimal / BigInteger numeric types that provide reasonably unlimited precision.  Some databases have their own comparative field types.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [fixed point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). You can do it, with an implementation like this:

```
public struct BigVector3
{
    private const float SCALE = 0.0001; // This controls the fixed point precision.

    public long x;
    public long y;
    public long z;

    public Vector3 GetRelativePos(BigVector3 other)
    {
        BigVector3 v = this;
        v.x -= other.x;
        v.y -= other.y;
        v.z -= other.z;

        return (Vector3)v;
    }

    public static implicit operator Vector3(BigVector3 value)
    {
        return new Vector3(value.x * SCALE, value.y * SCALE,  value.z * SCALE);
    }
}
```

But in the end, you still end up converting back to some kind of floating-point number in the end, for rendering, calculating physics with pretty much every major physics engine, etc.

The real solution is to increase the amount of precision in your numbers. `double` can handle any sub-solar-system scale with millimeter accuracy. Any game on the scale of a galaxy should really use relative positioning and math.

EDIT: "This makes me wonder how games like Star Citizen or Elite Dangerous do it"

These games don't need accurate positioning at such great distances. If you're in a space ship traveling faster than light then a millimeter is negligible. And vertex positions being inaccurate is only visible up close. You can simply render the ship interior separately from the rest of the world.